# libstdc++.so.3 => not found on CloudLinux, no SuperUser permissions, seemingly in chroot.

Tags: package-management, software-installation, libraries, dependencies, c++

I am trying to install the Linux x64 BOINC command-line interface client on a CloudLinux machine with x86_64 Architecture.
When I try to run the executable I get an error:

> ./boinc: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.3: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

When I do ldd of the boinc executable I find:

> ```
>     libstdc++.so.3 => not found
> ```

When I do yum install compat-libstdc++-33 I get

> CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf

I don't have access to any form of superuser permissions,
My account is very likely to be in a chroot.

How can I get my client running?

Comment: You really should specify your distro, as I could give you the command that is applicable.  If you don't know it run `lsb_release -a`.  If that doesn't work do this instead `cat /etc/*release`

Comment: Yeah I didn't put it b/c I didn't know, thanks for telling me how to find out. Unfortunately this is a webserver from greengeeks.com and when you lsb you get:

LSB Version:
Distributor ID: n/a
Description:    (none)
Release:        n/a
Codename:       n/a

And nothing for the cat. 

When I ran 'yum install compat...' you suggested below I got:
"CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf"

the only thing in /etc is my ftpquota folder

Comment: I have noticed that I can install programs so would my option be to install YUM so I can install the llibstdc?

Comment: Do you not even have root access?  Because that is something you always need to mention.  Otherwise you might be in a limited chroot shell.  You do have `yum` already installed, otherwise you would get a `command not found`  I would assume from that you are running some RedHat based distro.   You need to be root to install any package, otherwise you have to do everything in the local user.  try doing the command like this, `sudo yum install compat-libstdc++-33`

Comment: right, i don't mind doing it in the local user space. How can I change the yum flags to install it as local user?

Comment: No it's not a 'don't mind' thing, it's a last resort method.  YUM is nice and easy, but can only install new packages with root permissions.   Doing it locally is much more difficult, which is a concern for someone not that experienced with linux.  I can try and walk you through it anyway, but I don't know just how limited your account really is.  Is it a chroot, with little or no standard utilities, or is it just a normal account on a server .

Comment: Put it this way, if you have superuser accsess, this is a simple.  Which means you can log in directly as root user, or log in via the  `su` command, or execute commands with `sudo` prefixed.   If you don't have superuser permissions, you might want to consider asking the person who does to install the `compat-libstdc++-33` package for you.  If they refuse, than it might be worth the hassle of handling your dependencies locally.

Comment: Yes it looks that I am chrooted, b/c when I 
>ls -ld /proc/952883/root
I got permission denied.
If it is an inconvenience you don't have to walk me through it. Just point me in the right Google searches and I can RTM

Comment: I will walk you through it, if need be.  Is your server a VPS?  Like a virtual server?  Or are you just renting an account on someone else's server?  They almost always give superuser permissions with a Virtual Server, such as a rented XEN or KVM instance.

Comment: I will add the steps to my answer,  give me a couple minuets.

Comment: Its not a virtual server. Its the standard web hosting package from my understanding. Thank you TechZilla, I will reward you with a bounty

Comment: OK, i updated my answer.  run those commands, I'll actually go back and comment them a little better.  But they will work as is, comments would just be for you to know whats doing what.

Comment: OK i commented the commands for you, this should do the job...  BTW you only have 100 some points so it cool on the bounty.  You could always check out my other question answers.  Not saying to up them no matter what, But if you think I gave the best answer on them them vote up.  respond when you finished steps, and test it out.  If you get another error update your question with it, we can get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libstdc++ 3` is not the default `libstdc++` anymore.  You can still install it, though it is best to do so with your distro package util.  I'm assuming your BOINC client is for your arch, x86_64, and not compiled for x86.  The difference is significant in resolving dependency issues.

Considering you are on a regular user account, you should theoretically be able to do this locally.  I'm not sure which version of CloudLinux, but for now I'll assume it's 6.

```
## Set up Lib Path Environment
cd ~
mkdir lib
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib" >> .profile 

## Make tmp folder, download package in it
mkdir tmp 
cd tmp
wget http://64.131.90.31/PSA_10.4.4/thirdparty-rpm-CloudLinux-6-x86_64/compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6.i686.rpm

## Extract package files, get the parts we want
rpm2cpio compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6.i686.rpm | cpio -idmv
cp usr/lib/libstdc++-* ../lib

## Go in our lib folder, and create symlinks to the lib ldd told you was missing
cd ../lib
ln -s libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so libstdc++.so.3

## Go back to home, and source our profile changes.
cd ~
. .profile
```

Once you do all this, Try and run your client again.
You may need to log out and back in again, 
Tell me what happened afterwards!

Comment: Can I still do it if I don't have access to a distro manager? This linux is command line only. (is a web server)

Comment: You still can install packages from the command line, actually that's what i was referring to.  For example if you run redhat based distro.  The command would be `yum install compat-libstdc++-33`

Comment: If your using Ubuntu, You can get those dependancies installed with `getlibs`.  The deb is located http://frozenfox.freehostia.com/cappy/getlibs-all.deb Or get it by installing the gcc3 package.

But really, If you want a complete answer you need to tell me your distro.  Otherwise you will never get a better answer.  If I knew your distro, I could tell you with certainty which command you need to run.  If I already answered your question, mark it answered.

Comment: I found out its a distro called "CloudLinux"

Comment: Ya it's a RedHat based distro, using `yum` as its package management utility.

Comment: I also looked at the packages, and the one that has your lib is called `compat-libstdc++-296`.  It only came in i686, but was specified in the repo for x86_64.  So might as well go with it, we can always try other libs if it doesn't work.  As we already would have set up the environment.

Comment: Ok.

When we were constructing the file archive from std in I got:
`cpio: warning: skipped 63835 bytes of junk
cpio: warning: archive header has reverse byte-order
cpio: premature end of file`
And so no sub directories are created as they should with the -d flag.

Comment: B/c It says premature end of file, I redownloaded several times to make sure it all was. Still no luck. I tried removing the 'm' flag since I couldn't figure out what it was doing.

Comment: I have tried to no avail

`rpm2cpio compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-144.el6.i686.rpm > rpm.txt` `cat rpm.txt | cpio -idv`

Comment: OK, i want you to see if you even have `rpm2cpio` available. Run this command `rpm2cpio -h`, did you get `Usage: ...` or `command not found`?

Comment: I'm almost positive lack that command, you gotta check those things when you see new commands.  This is more important because you don't have a real server, its impossible to know just how limited the account is.  I will upload the files for you on my web server.  I won't keep them up for ever, so please do this ASAP.

Comment: ok run this `cd ~/lib ; wget http://nuzilla.net/tmp/libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so ; wget http://nuzilla.net/tmp/libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3`

Comment: then back at my instructions after this line `cd ../lib`

Comment: I downloaded those files into lib, and chmod them to 744. When I ran `rpm2cpio -h`  the cursor drops a line then stalls. `man rpm2cpio` returns a result. I checked the file system's bin and didn't see it. So you were right about rpm2cpio. I have the symbolic link in my /lib. When I do a cat of .profile I get `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib` It doesn't seem to have changed. I am still getting a not found error with ldd on the excutiable.

Comment: did you do the `. .profile` command, in the shell `.` is a built in command to source files. the `.profile` is in your `cd ~` directory.

Comment: If you get a different error, like a segfault.. That means we set the ENV correct, but need a different lib.  if you still get missing lib when you run the client, something is not perfect with the ENV profile.  You might not be sourcing correctly, do it manually with this cmd `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib` if need be.